# Cancel a Stripe authorization without refunding

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, capture, authorize

I have authorized a charge in Stripe, but later I realized I didn't need to capture the funds. When I searched for the answer I read I ought to issue a refund, but I'd rather not have the issuer/carrier know I issued a refund. Is there any other way to cancel an auth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know you're not going to capture the charge, it is recommended that you release the authorization by [refunding](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_refund) the uncaptured charge as soon as possible. Your customers will appreciate you not blocking their funds any longer than necessary.

That said, it is not required. If you don't capture the charge within seven days of the initial authorization, it will automatically be released.

Ref.: https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture

Comment: I know that i have to issue a refund ,But this will be included in my card summary that some refund was issued , But somehow if i manage to cancel that transaction before its second step then it will not reflect in any card details , That is what i want to achieve .Thanks .I think stripe does not provide any this way .